# Android - Task :app:mergeDexRelease FAILED

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, dex, react-native-svg

please consider that I'm not very familiar with Android development.

Trying to generate the Android signed bundle for my React Native app, I've stumbled upon the following error:

```
Task :app:mergeDexRelease FAILED
D8: Program type already present: com.horcrux.svg.Brush$BrushType
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
Learn how to resolve the issue at 
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
Program type already present: com.horcrux.svg.Brush$BrushType

...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
     Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
     Program type already present: com.horcrux.svg.Brush$BrushType
```

- I'm  aware that `BrushType` is a class from `react-native-svg`
- I've ran `gradlew app:dependencies` and found no module depending on `Brush` or anything related to `com.horcrux.svg` or `react-native-svg`
- Already tried cleaning project, deleting `.iml` files, invalidating Android Studio caches, rebuilding, reinstalling `node_modules` and so on
- Tried messing with `build.gradle` and `gradle.properties` with no luck
- I've read through [this android guide on duplicate classes](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes) also with no luck

I understand that there are 2 or more dependencies utilizing `com.horcrux.svg.Brush$BrushType` but I can't find them. I imagine that once I find them, I could do

```
implementation(:my-library) {
  exclude ...
}
```

Correct?

#### gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true

org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2560m
```

#### android/app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-appearance')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation project(':watermelondb')
    implementation project(':react-native-calendar-events')

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Solved by adding:

```
    implementation(project(':react-native-jitsi-meet')) {
      ...
      exclude group: 'com.facebook.react',module:'react-native-svg'
      ...
    }
```

In my case it was `react-native-jitsi-meet` that was causing the conflicts, I had to find it via trial and error.

Comment: any solutions found for this issue ?

Comment: Any solution found?

Comment: @jazzbpn I updated the post with the solution to my case

Comment: its working finally

Answer (score 3):

```
defaultConfig {
    ..............
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dependencies {
    ..............
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
}

public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
    ..............
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Resolved:
I have two packages `@react-native-masked-view/masked-view` (from previous developer) and `@react-native-community/masked-view`.
Just remove `@react-native-masked-view/masked-view` package and try build.

https://github.com/react-native-masked-view/masked-view/issues/100#issuecomment-841634389
Thanks to: Navipro70